# rails cookie doesn't store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I'm storing my cookie on user login like that

```
cookies.permanent[:bla_bla] = "bla bla"
```

if I put a puts after that it shows ok, but after that in application_controller

```
puts cookies[:bla_bla]
```

it's nil, I checked in browser and no cookie with this key is saved

Comment: Something clears the cookie, perhaps? Your browser, even?

Comment: it's the same for different browsers

Comment: Have you tried to use `cookies[:bla_bla]` instead of `cookies.permanent` ?